# Stacked bar graph from the same y-axis but different direction - Google Charts

Tags: google-visualization

I am using google charts.

I want something like this:[image]

I tried everything in here, but all in vain.

Please guide on what am I missing here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/18265316/613559.

Comment: @asgallant Thanks. Voted for a close. :)